# Баг с шапкой из неё торчит какая-то полоска ,на других страничках такого не появлялось. Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, header

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #b92b27, #1565c0)
}

.aq > * {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.navbar {
  height: 60px !important;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="sticky-top">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center ">
          <svg width="35px" height="35x" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-controller contriller mb-1 "
            fill="currentColor" style="color:#63ADD0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M11.119 2.693c.904.19 1.75.495 2.235.98.407.408.779 1.05 1.094 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.815-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773a11.307 11.307 0 0 1-.739-.809c-.126-.147-.25-.291-.368-.422-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.422-.243.283-.494.576-.739.81-.398.378-.877.705-1.513.772a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772.486-.485 1.331-.79 2.235-.98.932-.196 2.03-.292 3.119-.292 1.089 0 2.187.096 3.119.292zm-6.032.979c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.505C4.861 9.97 5.978 9.026 8 9.026s3.139.943 3.965 1.855c.164.182.307.35.44.505.214.25.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z" />
            <path
              d="M11.5 6.026a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1 1a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm2 0a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1 1a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-7-2.5h1v3h-1v-3z" />
            <path
              d="M3.5 6.526h3v1h-3v-1zM3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .258.966l-1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1-.612-.354zm9.976 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.353-.613l-1.932-.518a.5.5 0 1 0-.259.966l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 0 .612-.354z" />
          </svg>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.html">
            <h4>GameLand</h4>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 text-center ">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <a class="nav-link" href="news.html">Новости</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Игры</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Календарь</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <a class="nav-link " href="contacts.html">Контакты</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <a class="nav-link " href="contacts.html">Вход</a>
              </li>

              <!-- <div class="col-md-4 justify-content-center"> -->

              <!-- <li class="nav-item">
              <svg width="20px" height="20x" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search  search mr-4" fill="currentColor"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />

                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
              </svg></li> -->
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <div class="container h-100">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                    <div class="searchbar">
                      <input class="search_input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
                      <a href="#" class="search_icon"><i class="fas fa-search">
                          <svg width="23px" height="23px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search  search mb-2"
                            fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />

                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                          </svg>
                        </i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Везде посмотрела ,скопировала код с другой "не багованной" шапки и всё равно то же самое .Не могу понять в чём проблема**

Comment: в браузере в консоли разработчика вы бы на нее навели мышкой и посмотрели бы к какому элементу она относится - тогда было бы более-менее понятно, что это такое

Comment: Он у меня раньше не нажимался ,но я приблизила масштаб с помощью ctrl + колёсико мышки. Это оказался совсем другой блок который вкладывал в себя авторизацию .И вправду помогло. Спасибо!